# Persistence context cache the id and SQL query?

Tags: hibernate

If one call `session.save(customerObject)` then there is **no** insert into customer… query into the database. **Hibernate will set the id property ("sequence" or "Increment" generator) and bind the entity to a persistence context. The persistence context is synchronized with the database when `transaction.commit()` is called**.
Q: where will Hibernate set the id property?
Q: will the persistence context cache the sql query insert into customer… before synchronized with db ? I mean,when does sql generated(while doing save or session.flush/tx.commit)

EDIT: I got below from https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=951275&highlight=difference%20persist%20save

persist() is well defined. It makes a transient instance persistent. However, it doesn't guarantee that the identifier value will be assigned to the persistent instance immediately, the assignment might happen at flush time. The spec doesn't say that, which is the problem I have with persist().

persist() also guarantees that it will not execute an INSERT statement if it is called outside of transaction boundaries. This is useful in long-running conversations with an extended Session/persistence context.

A method like persist() is required.

save() does not guarantee the same, it returns an identifier, and **if an INSERT has to be executed to get the identifier (e.g. "identity" generator, not "sequence"), this INSERT happens immediately, no matter if you are inside or outside of a transaction.** This is not good in a long-running conversation with an extended Session/persistence context.

This is more confusing

Comment: Maybe you should break this up into multiple SO Questions as I'm not entirely sure whats being asked here. Also can you show how you have annotated the `Student.class` (specifically the id property.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question? Do you still have one?

Comment: @JBNizet if "sequence" or "Increment" generator is used, then Q: where will Hibernate set the id property?
Q: will the persistence context cache the sql query insert into customer… before synchronized with db ? I mean,when does sql generated(while doing save or session.flush/tx.commit)

Answer (score 0):

In general, Hibernate tries to write to the database as latest as possible, without compromising the correctness of the program, and by respecting the contract of the methods it offers.

Since `save()` is documented to assign an ID to the saved entity and return this ID, it generates the ID when `save()` is called, and returns it. This might mean that the entity is written to the DB or not, depending on the ID generation strategy.

Since `persist()` doesn't guarantee that an identifier is assigned when it's called, then you can't count on an ID to be assigned after `persist()` has been called. And you can't expect the entity to be written to the DB either, since that's not what `persist()` does. It's as simple as that.

Writes to the DB are only guaranteed to be executed when the session is flushed, automatically before the commit, or explicitely when `flush()` is called. You also have the guarantee that a write to the DB is executed if you execute a query whose results might depend on the pending writes.