# Merge will update the new session object update?

Tags: hibernate

Merge will update Name to Manik or Ankit ?

```
Student s1 = null;
s1 = (Student)session1.get(Student.class, new Integer(101));
session1.close();
s1.setName("Manik");
Session session2 = factory.openSession();
Student s2 = null;
Object o1 = session2.get(Student.class, new Integer(101));
s2 = (Student)o1;
s2.setName("Ankit");
Transaction tx=session2.beginTransaction();
session2.merge(s1);
```

Answer (score 1):

It should update the name to "Manik" (FYI the OP's original Q: [Persistence context cache the id and SQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15345419/persistence-context-cache-the-id-and-sql-query/15345943#15345943)) .

Hibernates weird mutable object cache (which IMHO I have always felt is stupid idea storing mutable objects in a cache) is discussed here: http://apmblog.compuware.com/2009/02/16/understanding-caching-in-hibernate-part-one-the-session-cache/

Merge should replace `s2` with `s1` reattaching `s1` to the context/session. It will save it to the db once you flush or close the session. If you had saved `s2` and then merged `s1` I think but not certain that you might get an Opportunistic Lock exception on save particularly if you share the session across threads.

The best way to know for sure is to write a unit test.

Answer (score 0):

this will update with name Manik.We will use merge to update the values with out considering the session state.

Answer (score 0):

This will update to Manik because of this : `Use merge() if you want to merge your modifications at any time without consideration of the state of the session.` from [hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-detached).